# Resample and interpolate pandas df

Tags: pandas, interpolation

I have a df that looks like the following:

```
TotalSpend   Date
  100    2001-04-26
  230    2001-05-12
  340    2001-06-16
  610    2001-07-31
  770    2001-08-31
```

I'm trying interpolate the data so I can see how much was spent during each month like so:

```
TotalSpend   Date     MonthlySpend
  110    2001-04-30      
  310    2001-05-31      200
  400    2001-06-30      90
  610    2001-07-31      210
  770    2001-08-31      160
```

I set the date column as the index and have tried to upsample the data (below) so that I have every day of the year and can then interpolate the missing values and select the month ends however this is proving troublesome.

```
       resample = realdf.resample('d').mean()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your totalSpend column has completely different values in the second dataframe.

Comment: Yes because they are corresponding to different dates, these are the interpolated values.